# When State-Owned Enterprises (SOE) start to be practiced widely in ancient times?

Tags: ancient-history, business-history

I was wondering if our current archaeology reveals whether ancient governments did business (trading for profit, raising cattle for profit, farm for profit, investing in their people's or other kingdom business, etc)?

Or they simply get it all from people's tax and getting new wealth from war?

Couldn't find "history" section in Wikipedia SOE page, or elsewhere so I don't know if SOE were really practiced widely in ancient times.

Comment: See e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palace_economy. But I think there are earlier examples from 3rd millenium B.C.

Comment: As I know, there are some governments had direct control of the trade of hard demand goods like salt. These actions are probably to prevent merchants have too much power to control the people but it will also make a lot of profit for the government.

Comment: I'm not sure that the concept of "state owned enterprise" has any meaning in the ancient world. The ancient world didn't have a concept of a firm or an enterprise, and the assumptions about private property were radically different. The goal of most economic activity wasn't to produce wealth or deepen capital, but a form of conspicuous consumption. I suspect that the answer to this question isn't going to be useful in the practice of history - like trying to measure the depth of the ocean with a stopwatch.

Comment: It's also worth remembering that the idea of a State as we understand it applies only poorly to most of the pre-Modern world.  The idea that there was an abstract State distinct from the people who ruled was alien. In many places and times, for example, the expectation was that the king should "live of his own" -- the king should do his kingly stuff paid for by his own resources. There was no State, there was just this rich and powerful man whose writ ran no farther than his own resources.

Comment: One weakness of the question is anachronism: most examples (and most probably the image of OP) of “enterprises” are typical to modern, capitalist economies. Spoils of war, simply personally owning stuff (land) by a leader, his family or whole community, monopolies of different trades, are more typical examples what I would call typical income sources for whatever equivalent to a state.

Answer (score 5):

The [Palace economies](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palace_economy) of the late Bronze Age seem to be something like one big state-owned enterprise. Textile workshops in the late Uruk period (late 4th millenium BC) are also usually assumed to have been state-owned.